# How to: Java multiple menus with quit option?

Tags: java, methods, menu

Ok, so my program has multiple menus.
For instance:
Hello!
would you like:
A Fries
B Hashbrowns
Q Nothing, close program

would you like:
A Ketchup
b Mustard
c none

etc etc.

SO, I'd like menu 1 to repeat after customer has chosen condiment. 
Additionally, I do NOT want the customer to be asked if they want a condiment if they've chosen Q to quit the program.
How do I make the program stop reading further menus if the customer wants to quit?

```
    if(menuChoice == 'A')
    {
        foodChoice= FRIES;
    }                       
    else
    {
        foodChoice= HASHBROWNS;
    }
```

I have a method for validations elsewhere
But basically you got a b or Q, right now A picks fries and anything else picks hashbrowns then continues with the menus.
I just don't know how to repeat this menu at the end.
Do I put the entire thing in a while loop?

Comment: Please show the code you have attempted so far.

Comment: Is this a Console application? Place your menu options into **while** loops. For your setup it looks like it may need nested **while** loops.

Comment: Personally, I would split each question into a method for a start. Then each answer for each question would link up to the corresponding method. So selecting `Q` for the first question would call `quit()`, which will say the final words and terminate the application.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of one basic way to accomplish the task. Within the code you can see the use of **while** loops. Loops allow you to let the User to make another menu selection especially when things go wrong like an improper selection was made. It also allows to User to select more than one item from the menu until no more are desired.

```
// Declare & initialize a Scanner object
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

// Will hold menu 1 selection
String menu1Selection = ""; 
// System line separator to use in console writes
String ls = System.lineSeparator(); 
// Will hold all meals ordered by User
String allMeals = "";

// Outer while loop (Main meal selection). This will
// continue to loop (taking orders) until e or E is 
// entered.
while (!menu1Selection.toLowerCase().equals("e")) {
    // Will hold the main meal selected
    String mainMeal = "";
    // Will hold all the condiments selected 
    // for the above main meal.
    String mealCondiments = "";
    // Display the main meal menu...
    System.out.print("Hello! What would you like to order:" + ls
            + "A:\tHamburger" + ls + "B:\tFries" + ls
            + "C:\tTwo Eggs" + ls + "D:\tHashbrowns" + ls
            + "E:\tExit Order System" + ls + "Choice --> ");

    // Get menu selection input from User
    menu1Selection = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    // Determine the meal selected based on the
    // menu item letter entered.
    switch (menu1Selection) {
        case "a":
            mainMeal = "Hamburger";
            break;
        case "b":
            mainMeal = "Fries";
            break;
        case "c":
            mainMeal = "Two Eggs";
            break;
        case "d":
            mainMeal = "Hashbrowns";
            break;
        case "e":
            // if e is entered then simply go to the
            // beginning of loop and allow the loop 
            // condition to exit it.
            continue;
        default:
            // If none of the above menu letters were selected 
            // then inform of invalid entry and allow the User 
            // to make a proper selection.
            System.err.println("Invalid menu entry! Try again..." + ls + ls);
            continue;
    }

    // Will hold menu 2 selection
    String menu2Selection = "";
    // Inner while loop for condiments selection. This will
    // continue to loop (adding condiments) until e or E is 
    // entered.
    while (!menu2Selection.toLowerCase().equals("e")) {
        // Display the Condiments Menu
        System.out.print(ls + "What condiments would you like with your "
                + mainMeal + "?" + ls + "A:\tKetchup" + ls
                + "B\tMustard" + ls + "C:\tMayonase" + ls + "D:\t"
                + "Relish" + ls + "E:\tNothing (Done)" + ls + "Choice --> ");

        // Get menu selection input from User
        menu2Selection = input.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        // Will hold the condiment name selected
        String condiments; 
        switch (menu2Selection) {
            case "a":
                condiments = "Ketchup";
                break;
            case "b":
                condiments = "Mustard";
                break;
            case "c":
                condiments = "Mayonase";
                break;
            case "d":
                condiments = "Relish";
                break;
            case "e":
                // if e is entered then simply go to the
                // beginning of loop and allow the loop 
                // condition to exit it.
                continue;
            default:
                // If none of the above menu letters were selected 
                // then inform of invalid entry and allow the User 
                // to make a proper selection.
                System.err.println("Invalid menu entry! Try again..." + ls + ls);
                continue;
        }

        // If a condiment was selected then add it to 
        // the mealCondiments string variable. Delimit
        // with a comma if more than one condiment is
        // being added (Ternary Operator is used for this).
        if (!condiments.equals("")) {
            mealCondiments+= mealCondiments.equals("") ? condiments : ", " + condiments;
        }
    }

    // Display the current meal order
    System.out.println(ls + "===========================================");
    System.out.println("Meal Ordered:\t" + mainMeal + " with " + 
                       mealCondiments);
    System.out.println("===========================================" + ls);
    // Add the ordered meal to the allMeals string variable.
    allMeals+= mainMeal + " with " + mealCondiments + ls;
}

// User has selected e or E to exit the Ordering System.
// Display all meals ordered by User & thank for business.
System.out.println(ls + "===========================================");
System.out.println("Your complete meal order is:" + ls + allMeals);
System.out.println("Thank you for your business. Bye-Bye.");

// Exit Application (Close)
System.exit(0);
```